# Can't test my @RestController: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

Spring Boot app.

My controller:

```
@RestController
public class ProductsController {
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

   @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
```

Here my test for my Rest controller:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductRestControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    ProductsController productsController;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
```

But I get runtime error when start test `testFindAll`

```
21:41:37.363 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@81715d3 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 0, missCount = 1]
21:41:37.375 [Test worker] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@4319ed88] to prepare test instance [com.myproject.ProductRestControllerIntegrationTest@63c46458]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myproject.ProductRestControllerIntegrationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myproject.repo.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add @SpringBootTest to your test configurations, under @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)